# Applescript to set radio button and submit form

Tags: automation, applescript

I'm trying to automate a webform I need to fill in and submit every morning. I'm stuck on setting the value of a radio button.

The webform where the radio button value must be set to "In":

[screenshot of web form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JeO8.png)

My Applescript which currently results in nothing happening:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
execute front window's active tab javascript "document.getElementByValue('In').checked = true; document.forms[0].submit();"
end tell
```

Any help is much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: OK I removed it. But my AppleScript contains Javascript, so I thought it would be helpful

Comment: Oh, my bad then, I apologize for the trouble  Try using `document.querySelector` like this: `document.querySelector('input[name="vsigninout"][value="In"]').checked = true`

Comment: Thanks so much, I just had to add \ to those values and it worked!